# Getting changes from one branch to another with new commits

Tags: git

Imagine you have a branch named `feature-x-alpha`, you do a lot of commits and get to the desired state. However, since you were in rush, these commits and its messages are a little weird to push.

Since you have a branch `feature-x` you can change to this branch and have as local changes the `feature-x-alpha`, now you can do few new more organised commits with this changes. Obviously since this are seen as different (although with some outcome) you will probably then delete branch `feature-x-alpha`.

You can achieve that while on the `feature-x-alpha` using the command

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/feature-x
```

which changes you to the branch `feature-x` but does not change the files of the working directory.

Seems to me that the symbolic-ref commands works fine for this, but this also this 3 commands seem to provide the same result.

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/my-branch

git reset my-branch 

git read-tree my-branch
```

I would like to understand the diferences of this 3 commands, and which one is better for this kind of usage (changing current branch without changing files of working directory, or something similar would be changing my working directory to the state of another branch other than the current).

Answer (score 0):

can you use higher order commands? Like this:

```
git checkout feature-x
git merge --squash feature-x-alpha
git commit -m "alpha"
git branch -D feature-x-alpha
```